# How can deleted questions be restored when they are duplicates?

Tags: discussion, support, deleted-questions, deleted-answers

This afternoon I answered a question by Doc Holiday. Now I found out [he asked it again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10198888) and wanted to vote for closing it as a duplicate, but the old one isn't there any more, so I guess he deleted it. That results in three questions:

- How can we counteract such behavior? He clearly should have edited the old one. Where should I flag? I guess a moderator could help?
- Where can I find whether he really deleted the question? Is it just gone without any references to its existence, shouldn't there be a log in his account?
- Where can I find my own answer to the deleted question? I might want to copy/reuse it for the newer question.

Related: [How can I find a deleted question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/92254/183280), [Can a question be restored if the owner deletes it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/100637/183280)

Comment: If you had a link, 10k+ users can see it, it's not gone. Moderators can probably see it in his profile, but us ordinary users can't.

Comment: Yes, the problem is I have no link. Is there at least a possibility to get the link - I don't need to look at the question?

Comment: I have no idea how to find a link, sorry. There are some gurus who can dig it up, though, you just need the luck that one of them steps in.

Comment: When I have had the need to do this, I just look in my browser history (especially if it's from the same day).

Answer (score 1):

Flag it for moderator attention, and describe what happened. Note that deleting a poorly-asked, unanswered question and re-posting a better one is perfectly appropriate - but if the previous question *had* been answered, there might be a good reason to resurrect it.

(Also note that even one up-vote on an answer, or more than one answer, will prevent the author from deleting his question)